# Корни "агро" и "агри"

Tags: иностранные-слова

В русском языке немало слов иноязычного происхождения с первой частью "агро" (агробиолог, агрохимик, агротехника, агроном и др.), но лишь одно слово с первым корнем "агри" - агрикультура (земледелие).  В то же время существует и слово "агрокультура" (повышение культуры земледелия). Интересно, почему только в слове "агрикультура" сохранилось это "агри"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова с "агро"/"агри" пришли в русский язык разными путями. "Аргрикулитура" - прямая транслитерация латинского "agriculture", попавшего в русский, видимо, через немецкий.
В тех же случаях, когда слово "сделано" уже в русском, используется обычная соединительная гласная О.
В некоторых источниках, правда, утверждается, что в "агри-" "И" (и еще "А" в "авиа-" и некоторых подобных случаях) тоже является соединительной гласной, но мне кажется, такое понимание в целом чуждо русскому языку.